# EXC_BAD_ACCESS thrown when adding objects to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when attempting to add objects to an array. I understand that this could mean I am pointing to something that doesn't exist in memory, or that the objects contain a nil value.

Code:

```
- (void)fadeInPlayer:(AVAudioPlayer *)player withMaxVolume:(float)maxVolume {

NSLog(@"player: %@", player);
NSLog(@"maxVolume: %f", maxVolume);

NSMutableArray *playerAndVolume = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: player, maxVolume, nil];

if (player.volume <= maxVolume) {
    player.volume = player.volume + 0.1;
    NSLog(@"%@ Fading In", player);
    NSLog(@"Volume %f", player.volume);
    [self performSelector:@selector(fadeInPlayer:withMaxVolume:) withObject:playerAndVolume afterDelay:0.5];
    //playerAndVolume array used here because performSelector can only accept one argument with a delay and I am using two...
    }

}
```

The strange thing is that when I print the objects I am trying to add to the console (shown as NSLogs above), they return data:

```
player: <AVAudioPlayer: 0x913f030>
maxVolume: 0.900000
```

The app crashes immediately after the NSLogs. The rest of the code works fine without the array, but I need to use it to call performselector:withObject:AfterDelay on the method.

So there must be a problem with how I am initialising the array, or maybe the object types, but I can't figure it out.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add a `float` to an `NSArray`. You'll have to wrap it in an `NSNumber`.

*But*

The real problem is that the first argument passed in is the `NSArray` you created, the second parameter passed into your function is the `NSTimer` that backs the `performSelector:afterDelay:...` methods. It doesn't spread out the objects in your array, it just passes the array as the first argument. If you are insistent upon remaining with this `API` design then you need to test the class of the first argument to see if it is an `NSArray` or an `AVAudioPlayer`. You could implement this function like this:

```
-(void)fadeInPlayer:(AVAudioPlayer *)player withMaxVolume:(NSNumber *)maxVolume {
    if ([player isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
        // This is a redundant self call, and the player and max volume are in the array.
        // So let's unpack them.
        NSArray *context = (NSArray *)player;
        player = [context objectAtIndex:0];
        maxVolume = [context objectAtIndex:1];
    } 

    NSLog(@"fading in player:%@ at volume:%f to volume:%f",player,player.volume,maxVolume.floatValue);

    if (maxVolume.floatValue == player.volume || maxVolume.floatValue > 1.0) return;

    float newVolume =  player.volume + 0.1;
    if (newVolume > 1.0) newVolume = 1.0;
    player.volume = newVolume;

    if (newVolume < maxVolume.floatValue){
        NSArray *playerAndVolume = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: player, maxVolume, nil];
        [self performSelector:@selector(fadeInPlayer:withMaxVolume:) withObject:playerAndVolume afterDelay:0.5];
    }
}
```

You would use this, wrapping the `float` in an `NSNumber`, like so:

```
[self fadeInPlayer:player withMaxVolume:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
```

Please note, this would be considered a very odd function, but this code does run.

Comment: Specifically, you need to use `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:maxVolume]`.

Comment: Great, thanks on both counts, was able to identify the problems and fix them. Cheers!